# Flutter AWS Amplify GraphQL Data Model Doesn't Access Other Related Data Model Class

Tags: flutter, amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I'm using **DynamoDB**, I created my Database with **Amplify GraphQL**. I have two data models, one is **User** and the other one is **SubscriptionType**. There is a **one-to-many** relationship between these models. Each user can only have one **SubscriptionType** but one **SubscriptionType** can belong to many **Users**.

My problem is when I make `amplify pull` I fetch my models but inside the **User** model class, I can't access the **SubscriptionType** model. Inside the **SubscriptionType** model, I can access the **User** model.

Here is my **ModelProvider.dart**

```
import 'package:amplify_core/amplify_core.dart' as amplify_core;
import 'SubscriptionType.dart';
import 'User.dart';

export 'SubscriptionType.dart';
export 'User.dart';

class ModelProvider implements amplify_core.ModelProviderInterface {
  @override
  String version = "4826e6c1ddaab534f826f93cee0d7763";
  @override
  List<amplify_core.ModelSchema> modelSchemas = [SubscriptionType.schema, User.schema];
  @override
  List<amplify_core.ModelSchema> customTypeSchemas = [];
  static final ModelProvider _instance = ModelProvider();

  static ModelProvider get instance => _instance;
  
  amplify_core.ModelType getModelTypeByModelName(String modelName) {
    switch(modelName) {
      case "SubscriptionType":
        return SubscriptionType.classType;
      case "User":
        return User.classType;
      default:
        throw Exception("Failed to find model in model provider for model name: " + modelName);
    }
  }
}


class ModelFieldValue<T> {
  const ModelFieldValue.value(this.value);

  final T value;
}
```

Here is the error:

[image]

Here is my Data Modeling on Amplify:

[image]

Comment: Finally, I found a solution. Changing my property (relationship name) key name to lowerCase. The problem is my model property name conflicts with another function or property name. It would be best if you changed your property name.